# How do I get access to PUT data with the ramaze framework?

Tags: ruby, ramaze

I'm attempting to use Ramaze, the ruby framework, to implement a RESTful controller.  I can't seem to gain access to the data in the request when I send a PUT, however.   Sample code:

```
require 'ramaze'

class PutController < Ramaze::Controller
 map '/'

 def index
    "Argument of "+request[:id]
 end
end

Ramaze.start
```

And my interacting with it via curl:

```
% curl -d id=5 "http://localhost:7000/"
Argument of 5

% curl -v -X PUT -d id=5 "http://localhost:7000/" > /dev/null
...
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
[With a backtrace revealing that the request object is nil]
```

Am I doing something wrong?  How am I supposed to be getting at the body of the PUT request in Ramaze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ramaze'

class PutController < Ramaze::Controller
 map '/'

 def index
    "Argument of "+request.POST['id']
 end
end

Ramaze.start
```

it works for PUT as well as POST and GET.